# PHP move_uploaded_file() function is not working

Tags: php

`move_uploaded_file($fileSrc, $target);` is not working, I get the image name and extension of the image but image is not going to target folder. I don't know why this is not working. I am working on xampp localhost

```
if(isset($_FILES["filesToUpload"]["name"]))
{
    $name=$_FILES['filesToUpload']['name'];
    $fileSrc=$_FILES['filesToUpload']['tmp_name'];
    $extnsion= pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $fileName = "tourGuides_" . $id . '.' . $extnsion;
    $target="../img/guide_profile/".$fileName;
    move_uploaded_file($fileSrc, $target); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing you forgot, is that you cannot move a file based on just its name. You should also provide PHP with the location of that file.

This can be as simple as:

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]); // or tmp_name
$target="../img/guide_profile/".$fileName;
move_uploaded_file($target_file, $target);
```